# Pantheon Terminal Will not work after uninstalling zsh

Tags: pantheon-terminal, pantheon

Just got a fresh copy of elementary after I messed it up.

Then again, I just installed zsh and I was configuring it, messed up the configuration. After that Oh well, lets remove and reinstall it. As I removed I realised that now I do not have a working terminal!

***I tried the following***
 * When I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, I'm directed to the original terminal but it asks for a login and when I do that it just redirects me to the same login command again.
 * Tried Starting My Terminal. It is simply blinking.
[image: Nothing Happens in the terminal]

Please help me fix my terminal again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I had sublime text installed. Just traverse to `\etc\` and then edit file named `passwd`.
It would require you to have admin access, but if you have replace all `zsh` references with `bash`.

I had to change only one line `uname:x:1000:1000:user,,,:/home/uname:/bin/zsh` to `uname:x:1000:1000:user,,,:/home/uname:/bin/bash`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chsh` utility change the login shell of a user in a terminal window.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```